# Optimize date range query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Date range queries seem to be hitting my indexes, but are still slow. Approx ~30M rows in table. Anything I can do to speed up?

```
User.messages.where(message_type: 'incoming').where(created_at: start_date..end_date).explain


Message Load (8322.3ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."user_id" = $1 AND "messages"."message_type" = $2 AND ("messages"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-09-23 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-09-23 23:59:59.999999')  [["user_id", 1], ["message_type", "incoming"]]

QUERY PLAN

Index Scan using index_messages_on_created_at on messages  (cost=0.09..21223.80 rows=136690 width=527)
       Index Cond: ((created_at >= '2016-09-23 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2016-09-23 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone))
       Filter: ((user_id = 1) AND ((message_type)::text = 'incoming'::text))
       (3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have an index on `(user_id, message_type, created_at)`. This will allow postgres to run the provided query by only using that index.

Comment: This seems to help with tighter date ranges (single day), but is ignored on week/month date ranges when too many rows are queried.

Comment: Did you run `ANALYZE` on the table? Run `ANALYZE "messages";` and then run the query again.

Comment: Same thing. The queried row count is over 500K for some users and the table has only 30M rows. Is it possibly not selective enough?

Comment: It does work for other users when then queried row count is much smaller...

Comment: So, are you saying that for a specific `user_id`, specific `message_type`, and a range of `created_at` you expect to get 500K rows?

Comment: Yes. I should note that I'm actually performing a "count" on these rows

Comment: Maybe you should cache the counts for each user, e.g. have a table where you store for each user and for each month, the messages of that user for that month.